# Share object with process (multiprocess)

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm just starting with multiprocessing and i'm trying to share object between main and process. Code example:

```
import multiprocessing

class User(object):

  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.age = 0

  def getNameAndAge(self):
    return self.name + ' ' + str(self.age)

def define_age(user, age):
  user.age = age

bob = User('bob')

print bob.getNameAndAge()

define_age(bob, 25)

print bob.getNameAndAge()

p = multiprocessing.Process(target=define_age, args=(bob, 35))
p.start()
p.join()

print bob.getNameAndAge()
```

Output:

```
bob 0
bob 25
bob 25
```

How share bob object to get correct age ?

Comment: In a far sense Managers could be of interest: http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-remote-manager

Comment: @User it is not huge solution ? No simple "memory shared" solution ? (note: i've try with  Proxy Objects without success)

Comment: Where did you find proxy objects?

Comment: @User: http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#proxy-objects

Comment: This proxy would be exactly what I would look for. I have implemented an alternative you can try: https://github.com/niccokunzmann/pynet/tree/master/process the reference file is it. cou need to clone the whole repository or download it. This is an example: https://github.com/niccokunzmann/pynet/blob/master/documentation/done/tools.rst