# How to share a customized variable when using multiprocessing in Python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

There is a **bloom filter** object that created by `pybloom`, a Python module. Assume that I have over 10 million strings that waiting for *add* into this object and the general way to do so is:

```
from pybloom import BloomFilter

# initialize a bloomfilter object
bf = BloomFilter(int(2e7)) 

for i in string_list:
    bf.add(i)
```

But this costs too much time specially when the `string_list` is really long. Since my computer(windows7) is 4-core CPU and I want to know if there is a multi-process way to make fully use of CPU and fast the `add` method.

I know a little about `multiprocessing`, but I cannot solve the problem that exchanging customized objects, such as `bf` above, between processes.

Forgive my poor English and show me the code if you can. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe try to use Queue in Python, which is designed for multi-processing.

Comment: This would be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21968278/multiprocessing-share-unserializable-objects-between-processes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with `pybloom` or `BloomFilter` objects, but a quick look at the code reveals that you can `union` multiple `BloomFilter` objects.

Based on your size of your `string_list` you may create a `Pool` of `n`. For simplicity, say `n=2`. Logic here is: For, say `x` strings in `string_list` - divide it in `2` lists of size `x/2` each. Then create a separate process to process these.

You can have something like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
with Pool(n) as p:
    bloom_filter_parts = p.map(add_str_to_bloomfilter, divide_list_in_parts(string_list))
    # Now you have a list of BloomFilter objects with parts of string_list in them, concatenate them
    res_bloom_filter=concat_bf_list(bloom_filter_parts)
```

Code for `add_str_to_bloomfilter`:

```
def add_str_to_bloomfilter(str_list_slice):
    res_bf = BloomFilter(capacity=100)
    for i in str_list_slice:
        res_bf.add(i)
    return res_bf
```

You have to add code for `divide_list_in_parts` and `concat_bf_list`. But I hope you get the logic.

Also, read this: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: I solve the problem with your logic. It does not match my original thoughts very much, but it works. Thank your again for the answer.