# Python - Multiprocessing StarMap with two arguments

Tags: python, multiprocessing, iterable, starmap

I've a function that runs multiple queries in parallel but I'm having some troubles to run my function using multprocessing with more than argument. I've this code:

```
def run(args):
    query, cursor = args
    cursor.execute(query)
with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=10) as pool:
    args = (product(queries),cursor)
    results = pool.starmap(run(args))
```

If I run only `pool.starmap(run(product(queries)))` it works well, however I have the need to pass also the cursor object.

How I can do that?

I'm having the following error:

```
TypeError: starmap() missing 1 required positional argument: 'iterable'
```

Comment: Did you mean `starmap(run, args)`? When you do `pool.starmap(run(product(queries)))` you just execute `run` with the arguments and then pass the result of that function, `None`, to `starmap.

Comment: If I run starmap(run,args) I got TypeError: cannot pickle 'SSLSocket' object

Comment: Just to get this clear: You want to execute `run` with each of the different combinations in `itertools.product(queries)` (whatever queries is), and each with _the same_ `cursor`, right?

Comment: Yes, I want to execute multiple queries in parallel with the same cursor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some problems with your code:

- you call `run` with parameters, then pass the result to `starmap`, but you have to pass both the function and its parameters separately to `starmap`
- your args are a tuple of first the product of all queries, then the cursor, but you rather want to combine each of those query-combinations with the cursor
- your function expects a single parameter that you then unpack inside the function, so you should use `map`; for `starmap` it should be `def run(query, cursor)`

Try this:

```
import multiprocessing
import itertools

def run(args):
    query, cursor = args
    print("running", query, cursor)

queries = ["foo", "bar", "blub"]
cursor = "whatever"
    
with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=10) as pool:
    args = ((args, cursor) for args in itertools.product(queries))
    results = pool.map(run, args)
```

There may be more "upstream" errors, like that `SSLSocket` stuff, but this should at least (try to) call the function with the correct parameters.

Answer (score 1):

[`pool.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap) takes two arguments: the function and a list of arguments.

From the docs:

```py
pool.starmap(func, [(1,2), (3, 4)])
# results in [func(1,2), func(3,4)]
# I guess in your case would be

pool.starmap(run, [ product(queries), cursor ])
```

Comment: I got 'TypeError: cannot pickle 'SSLSocket' object' with this code :(

Comment: You can not share objects that are not pickable between threads (like sockets) but you can pass details on how to reproduce or share them. You can see more details [here (Share unserializable objects between processes - StackOverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21968278/multiprocessing-share-unserializable-objects-between-processes)

Comment: Also if you can instantiate your `SSLSocket` inside the `run` method would be simpler